# Select child css without a specific element

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors

I want to apply css style in all `mat-tab-group` element without impacting the style of `app-form` element

```
<div class="area">
  <childhere></childhere>
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="..." [label]="label">
      <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <div class="inside-tab">
          <mat-form-field>...</mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>...</mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>...</mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>...</mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <app-form></app-form>
      </form>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

I've try using **:not** property  but it's not working

```
mat-tab-group > mat-tab > form :not(:last-child){
  background-color: #009926; //to test
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't select a parent based on the existence of a child or otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand why you're not using something like `mat-tab-group > mat-tab > form .inside-tab { background-color: #009926; }`? Is `app-form` css being overridden by specificity? Or does it have `background: transparent` and the color shows through?

Comment: hi @coll, app-form is an angular component that have his specific css style, your code select only .inside-tab element, i want to apply style to mat-tab-group element without changing style of app-form.

Comment: `mat-tab-group > mat-tab > form > *:not(app-form), mat-tab-group > mat-tab > form > *:not(app-form) *` should work for you

Comment: @ciekals11 it seems to be correct but when i use ">" it's not working because its a element from angular material ?

Comment: @AliSolomon where are you placing this ">"? Can you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
mat-tab-group > mat-tab > form {
  background-color: #009926; //to test
}
```

```
mat-tab-group > mat-tab > form:last-child {
  background-color: unset;
}
```

This way, last child background will fallback to default.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hg8urh?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Snippet:

```css
div > div > * {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white
}

div > div > *:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
<p>first</p>
<p>secont</p>
<p>last</p>
  </div>
</div>
```